# How to ls files with output starting on a specific letter?

Tags: bash, ls

I want to `ls` all files from `/bin` that starts with letter `s`, and this is the furthest I could think, but it does not print out information:

```
ls /bin | grep ^s
```

Does anyone have a hint?

Comment: A hint? See `man ls` to learn about `-l` and `-d`. Investigate [globbing](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/glob) to learn about `/bin/s*` and such. Can you put these together and take it from here?

Comment: Yes, thank you.

Comment: `ls -l /bin/[acr]*` should be fine then.

Comment: one more hint: `grep -E ^s`

Comment: Please add your desired output (no description, no images, no links) to your question (no comment).